# Is it possible to know why we received badges?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

There are a lot of badges in Modern Warfare 2. Some are ugly or funny.

I would like to know why I received them. I know that the reason is written when you receive them, but, after a while, I don't remember.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you mean callsigns, there's a full list on the [Call of Duty Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/) for [titles](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Titles) and [emblems](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Emblems).

Comment: Thanks for the great references. Very inspirational...I guess this is how they hook us!